# Faces Message after download a file in JSF

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

Good Day, I have download file function in Java that is being called in JSF.

But after the file was downloaded, the FacesMessage is not shown in the page..

Is there any reason behind it?

I have a code in xhtml:

```
<h:commandButton id="submit" value="#{message.btn_submit}" action="#{bean.doProcess}"/>
```

in Backing bean:

```
public void doProcess() {
MessageUtil.addMessage("SOME MESSAGE");
FacesContext faces = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                       HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) faces.getExternalContext().getResponse();
                       response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                       response.setContentLength(pdf.length);

                       List<String> ids= request.getIds();
                       String fname = utilsFactory.getPDFFilename(hwbs);

                       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("attachment; filename=\"")
                        .append(fname)
                        .append("\"");
                       String removeNewLine = sb.toString().replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");

                    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", removeNewLine);
                       try {
                           ServletOutputStream out;
                           out = response.getOutputStream();
                           out.write(pdf);
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           LOGGER.error("Unable to print to outputstream", e);
                       }
                       faces.responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: You question contains too little information to answer. How do you call download file function, what that function contains, how are you trying to show message ...

Comment: please provide the code for what you have done so far

Comment: Any idea or suggestions?